# 'messy' string to int conversion java

Tags: java, string, types, integer

In my code I need to convert a String to an Integer - the String comes from the extraction of metadata, which is then compared to a array of numbers and their corresponding genres. Unfortunately the string doesn't simply contain numbers, it contains some spaces and brackets, meaning the usual:

```
String genre = mf.genre(byteArr);
 // this gets the metadata from the byte array (It's of no consequence to this but it makes it easier to understand)
int genreInt = Integer.parseInt(genre);
System.out.println(genreInt);
```

doesn't work, returning

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "    (13)"
```

As the 13 (for example) is the only part of this I want/need, what would be the easiest way to go about obtaining just this number from the 'messy' string? thanks

Comment: Regex: `\\d+`.. Or simply: `genre.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
System.out.println(genre.replaceAll("[^0-9]",  ""));
```

Comment: You don't need to `trim()` since spaces will be replaced as well.

Comment: Note that if there are 2 numbers, this will concatenate them, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yea You're right.
Dan, i think there are many cases we can think about, but i answer based on the input in this question.